# Count cells in row relative to max(A) (most current date) in first column

Tags: google-sheets

The image below shows a sample of what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image: Sheet Image]

Basically I need a formula that will check column A for the most recent date and then count how many "Present" cells in the corresponding row there are. It's meant to keep a count like attendance, but these are results of Google forms so a new row is added from the form response daily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
=sum(arrayformula(if(array_constrain(sort(A2:F, 1, false), 1, 6) = "PRESENT", 1, 0)))
```

Explanation:

1. `sort` sorts the range A2:F by the first column, descending order. So the most recent entry is first.
2. `array_constrain` keeps only the first row.
3. `if` transforms the entries to 1 if "Present" and 0 otherwise
4. `arrayformula` says step 3 applies to each of the entries
5. `sum` adds up the values